# How to add expression calculated field with query

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am using an Access 2010 DB and have a simple table with the following data:

[image]

I would like to add by query additional field named batch number. The batch number shall divided my series into batches. While if number of pipes is 0 then the batch number is 0, and if the number is between zeros the serie should get the same batch number. please see attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

when creating a new table on design mode after entering file name when choosing the type of the field in the data type column you choose calculates Don’t know if it’s the same on access
 2010 but it’s work on 2013 et 2016
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.